# Handling single quotes in plsql

Tags: plsql

I am trying to write a procedure that writes the following to a file.How to i handle the single and double quotes such that they are also write as is on the file and text will be an in  varchar2 variable

```
<div class="tree">

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleText');">||text||</a> <== click Here
<div onclick="javascript:toggle('toggleText');">

<div id="toggleText" style="display:none; border-width:2px; border-style:solid"><H1>||text||</H1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare
v_val varchar2(500):=q'[<div class="tree">

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleText');">||text||</a> <== click Here
<div onclick="javascript:toggle('toggleText');">

<div id="toggleText" style="display:none; border-width:2px; border-style:solid"><H1>||text||</H1></div>
</div>]';
begin
dbms_output.put_line(v_val);
  end;
```